# User submitted content to mysql with moderation: separate table?

Tags: mysql, version-control, revision

In an mysql table I would like to get data from user, however the data would need to be moderated by admin first. My question is that is it normal to just insert into the original table and use a field as flag of the moderation status? Or have a separate table of pre-moderated posts and do the insertions only at moderation?

I think both method would work but I am not sure if I miss out other considerations here. Hope someone experienced can tell me the established/preferred way to do that.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I have the exact same question and haven't been able to google a suitable response.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a not-huge data set I'd recommend just adding a flag column that allows you to show or hide user data. This will require fewer and easier queries to work with and should make your life a lot easier than juggling the data between multiple identical tables. Additionally, if you want to add something like a button for "report this content as BAD" you could remove the content from other results while only "soft deleting" it from public visibility.